# passed UIButton AttributeTitle in new controller title

Tags: ios, swift

I want to ask how can I passed in my attributeTitle in UIButton into new controller navigation title. I have 3 button with the exact setup this is my code.

```
let fiqhButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let attributeText = NSAttributedString(string: "Fiqh", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 60), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    button.setAttributedTitle(attributeText, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "milada-vigerova-36934-unsplash").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.tag = 1
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePushVC), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

and this is my handlePushVC

```
@objc fileprivate func handlePushVC() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let searchVideoController = SearchVideoController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVideoController, animated: true)
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the button from your `handlePushVC` function, or simply by calling `self.fightButton`. If you want to do the first option, you can change your target like so:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handlePushVC(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Then inside your function, you can get the sender/button's attributed title, and pass it to your controller to be pushed:

```
@objc func handlePushVC(_ button: UIButton) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let searchVideoController = SearchVideoController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    searchVideoController.title = button.attributedTitle(for: .normal)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVideoController, animated: true)
}
```

As you can see, we're passing `button.attributedTitle(for: .normal)`, so you need to make an optional property `NSAttributedString?` there.

Then finally, in your `SearchVideoController`'s `viewDidLoad()`, you assign that variable to your navigation title with this short function:

```
/// Sets the title with attributed string
public func setAttributedTitle(_ title: String, color: UIColor, font: UIFont) {

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color,
                      NSAttributedString.Key.font : font as Any]
    titleLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
}
```

I hope this helps!